# How to store user auto in database?

Tags: django

I created a form for adding products to an e-Commerce site. The form isn't working perfectly.

**First issue:** I  want to store the user automatically by submitting the form. I actually want to store Who did add the product individually.

**Second Issues:** The image field is not working, the image is not stored in the database.

*How can I fix these issues? help me*

***forms.py:***
from django import forms
from .models import Products
from django.forms import ModelForm

```
class add_product_info(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('product_title','product_image')
```

***model.py:***

```
class Products(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="merchandise_product_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length = 250)
    product_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to = "1_products_img")
```

***views.py:***

```
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = add_product_info(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Successfully product added.")
            return redirect("add_product")

    form = add_product_info
    context = {
        "form":form 
    }
    return render(request, "add_product.html", context)
```

***templates:***

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="needs-validation" style="font-size: 13px;" novalidate="" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark ms-auto" style="font-size:13px;">Add</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `.user` of the `.instance` wrapped in the form to the logged in user (`request.user`). Furthermore you need to pass both `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to the form to handle files.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = add_product_info(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully product added.')
            return redirect('add_product')
    else:
        form = add_product_info()
    context = {
        'form': form 
    }
    return render(request, 'add_product.html', context)
```

I would also advise *not* to use `null=True` nor `blank=True`, unless a field is really optional. Likely the `product_title` should not be optional, nor should the `user` be, since you use `CASCADE` in case the user is removed.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Forms in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`add_product_info`</s> to `ProductInfoForm`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Product` instead of <s>`Products`</s>.

Answer (score -1):

why are you using the ForeignKey with your user. the first issue i notice is with the class Meta. Pass this as a list not tuple.

```
class add_product_info(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = [
                 'product_title',
                 'product_image',
                 ]
```

then try this as well.

```
class Products(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="merchandise_product_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Using a tuple or a list makes not much dfference: Django only requires this to be an *iterable* of strings. Furthermore a `OneToOneField` would mean that a `User` can have *at most* one `Product` object?